# Bootstrap File Input -Kartik display upload error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, file, input

i am using Bootstrap File Input for uploading mulitple images,and i am interesting what JSON data i must send back so i can display error for each induvidual image.

**example what i send back**

```
{"error":"There where 2 errors during upload!","errorkeys":[0,2]}
```

so first and third image was not uploaded but error is not displayed and i ged this error in console:`ReferenceError: key is not defined

I just want to show usser witch image did not upload,do i need send aditional data or?`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm using yii2 widget but it is the same.
In php response, when there's an error, I write:

```
  $Response='There where 2 errors during upload! :
      <br> Error 1: Image 1 <br> Error 2: Image 3';
  echo json_encode(['error'=>$Response]);
```

You should write in a general panel error and you explain the errors(write in html).

Answer (score 0):

You are sending back good data. Problem is in fileinput.js (exact line number can be found in dev console).

You have to change

```
keys = isEmpty(data) || isEmpty(data.errorkeys) ? [] : data.errorkeys;
```

to

```
var keys = isEmpty(data) || isEmpty(data.errorkeys) ? [] : data.errorkeys;
```

At least that is what i have done in my case and it's working fine after that.

Dont forget to clear old assets in case of Yii / Yii2 which will hold old version of .js file untill you delete it.